# Connection Problem of Night vision IR led for RasPi Camera

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

I have a pair of these [IR leds](https://www.sainsmart.com/products/2-pcs-night-vision-infrared-ir-led-lights-for-raspberry-pi-cameras) that I am powering independently of the RasPi camera using 5V. I have placed them away from camera and each other and soldered wires to the copper pads after correctly determining the terminals.

[image]

But there are several issues that come up with this arrangement.
a) In the start, the leds are getting powered but after some time (about 2 minutes), they start blinking.
b) The frequency of blinking gradually starts increasing.
c) The copper pads where wires are soldered also gets heated up.

I assumed that the connections must be right or else the leds would not have worked for the first few minutes. I could find a lot of information on the camera but not on these lights.

I have shown the connection diagram for leds, but I tried testing one led at a time. I am using 5V DC and the current consumption of one led is about 0.29A. [image]

I am just puzzled as to why this is happening. Are they supposed to be connected together with the screws and nuts as shown in various [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOCA60gGHAs)? Why is it making a difference?

Comment: You need a larger power supply, at least 1A, but around 1.2A would be better. The current draw of each of those LED's is 500mA at 5V, you have 2.

Comment: @RonBeyer I am using a bench power supply, I am operating the leds at 5V DC but the current consumption one led shows is about 0.28A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like it is overheating, which at 3W would not surprise me. You need to attach them to some sort of heat sink.

[image]

That big copper pad on the back sort of suggests the thing is meant to be either soldered down to a larger PCB or thermal compounded to a heat sink.

Test the pad first though and see what it is connected to. It may be connected to the live side so electrical insulation may be required between device and heat-sink.

Comment: Thank you! I kind of suspected that, but what I did not understand is how does overheating make the led turn on and off? Shouldn't it just shut off completely when it is overheated?

Comment: @AmyM well that depends on the exact mechanism. Either way it will shut off then cool enough to turn back on then repeat.

Comment: It's likely the heat is affecting the light sensor and switch. You need to alter the pot to set the turn on/off threshold. The LED itself should never flash (it's a simple power LED) but it does get quite hot (I have some, and they get very hot to the touch).

Comment: @AmyM if you notice in the tutorial you posted he mentions he added the heatsinks at about 2:50 in.

Comment: @AmyM: Flashing, or intermittent connections is a typical failure mode of LEDs which are cheaply constructed, physically damaged, or used with too high a current. When this happens, the LEDs can go through thermal expansion which breaks the internal connection. On cooling, they might reconnect, the LEDs may illuminate again. The cycle continues resulting in flashing. Bond wire breakages can give similar results as can internal shorts of the LED substrate material. This can also lead to LEDs flashing between different brightness. If yours are flashing then they are probably damaged.

Comment: A big part of the issue may be the 0.6A power supply supplying 2 LED's that take 500mA each. The power supply is severely undersized.

Answer (score 1):

I have these LEDs too. There's a tiny potentiometer (near the black wire in your picture) which adjusts their brightness and changes how ambient light affects the light induced shutoff. If you turn them up too bright (without adequate heatsink) they start flashing. I don't know if this is a safety feature or a failure mode, but if you turn down the brightness using the potentiometer they resume working normally (so far!).

Answer (score 0):

I note when these LEDs are attached the camera module, they are actually running at 3.3v, and also you might find that the actual current avialable via the camera ribbon cable is less than the LED's are trying to draw, so in that way, they are running at a much lower power level than your configuration  - natively conneted to 5V with presumably a higher maximum current avilablity.

Answer (score 0):

I have what looks like the same product and found this:

The LED board appears to have an AP1231 voltage regulator (labeled 4VTD on mine but looks like 4XY6 ? on yours) which has 300mA overcurrent protection. Since you're drawing 290 mA, it may be shutting down on overcurrent then starting up again, causing flicker.

You can set the current with the trimpot. I use it set to 150 mA and the LDR open circuit (always on).

The regulator is a linear regulator so all the power in dropping from 5V to the LED's 1.4 V is dissipated as heat in the regulator and transistors. That's probably the cause of heating - mainly the regulator not so much the LED itself.

I don't think you need any external heatsink if you set the current to 150 mA and run them off 3.3V. I've run these continuously for many 12 hour periods that way with no heatsink and not seen any dimming or failure.

The camera module it comes with powers it at 3.3V so it wouldn't heat up as much as your 5V and it might not be good for its longevity to use 5V, especially not at 300 mA.